# string operations in mysql [counting a string in different columns]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table food with columns 'onSunday' 'onMonday' and 'onTuesday' :

```
person      onSunday              onMonday       onTuesday
1          Biscuits: Chocolates   Biscuits       Chocolates
2          Chocolates             Biscuits       Pi: chocolates
```

From this set {Biscuits, chocolates , Pi},

Is there a way to get total count of Biscuits, Chocolates and Pi for person 1 in mysql?

Expected result for person 1:

```
 Biscuits=2
 Chocolates = 2
 Pi = 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your relation design is quite awkward. It doesn't even comply to first normal form, since your column values are not atomic (I see a colon seperated list in there, right?). I could answer with a long convoluted query, but it would be better to change your design first.

This might be a better design:

```
CREATE TABLE meals(
    person INT,
    meal TEXT,
    day TEXT
)
```

Then you would have one row per meal in this table, e.g.,

```
person meal day                          
1 Biscuits onSunday
1 Chocolates onSunday
1 Biscuits OnMonday
1 Chocolates onTuesday  
...
```

Then your query would be as easy as this:

```
SELECT meal, COUNT(*) FROM meals WHERE person = 1 GROUP BY meal
```

The good thing is that you can add new meals without having to change the query. In the other answer, the query has to be adjusted for each new meal you introduce. You can also add the remaining weekdays without having to add new columns.

Comment: I think you should answer the question first. Redesigning the table is quite another thing. You can say it as a side note.

Comment: @RagingBull: Well, you did answer the question already so I don't have to do it ;). IMHO you sometimes have to answer not what is requested but how it should be done. A table design like this is just trashing the relational model completely. Basically, your answer falls back to using string operations to mimic features that the relational model itself offers. The necessity of string operations is always a strong indicator that the design is substantially flawed.

Comment: How often do you think someone writing a query can completely re-factor the DB? People may not have control over their schema. We shouldn't assume that they can change the structure of their table without consulting with their DBAs. BTW, I appreciate the suggestion. ;-)

Comment: @RagingBull I would find it quite likely that someone asking a question like this is a student or someone else doing their own database work. Hopefully a DBA would know about normalization.

Comment: @RagingBull: If *this* schema is really from a productive environment of a real company, then Op should mandate the schema change. If the DBA refuses and keeps this schema, quitting the job immediatly seems to be the best suggestion I could give in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT person,
     (LENGTH(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday), 'Biscuits', '')))/8 AS Biscouits,
     (LENGTH(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday), 'Chocolates', '')))/10 AS Chocolates,
     (LENGTH(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday), 'Pi', '')))/2 AS Pi
FROM food
```

Result:

```
PERSON  BISCOUITS   CHOCOLATES  PI
1       2           2           0
2       1           1           1
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d33dc/7).

**Explanation:**

Here we concatenate fields `onSunday`,`onMonday` and `onTuesday` together and find the occurence of biscuits, chocolates and pi from the concatenated field.

**Advantage:**

This query will get you the right answer even if `onSunday` has multiple biscuits in it.

**NB:** To search for a certain person, use a `WHERE` clause at the end of the query. Like:

```
SELECT person,
     (LENGTH(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday), 'Biscuits', '')))/8 AS Biscouits,
     (LENGTH(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday), 'Chocolates', '')))/10 AS Chocolates,
     (LENGTH(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(onSunday,onMonday,onTuesday), 'Pi', '')))/2 AS Pi
FROM food
WHERE person=1
```